# Add variable to SQL query to get day by day results

Tags: php, sql, yii

In my model I have the following query which average $probe values hour by our for the last day available in the database.

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$command=$connection->createCommand("SELECT AVG($probe), TIME FROM tbl_sensors GROUP BY DATE(TIME), HOUR(TIME) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 24");
$dataReader=$command->query();
```

Now I'd like to modify this query to get the result for yesterday, the day before yesterday etc.

My first thought was to add a variable fed by the controller modify LIMIT parameters. Though the following:

```
SELECT AVG($probe), TIME FROM tbl_sensors GROUP BY DATE(TIME), HOUR(TIME) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 24, 48
```

returns 48 values instead of 24. I don't understand why is that?

Any pointers welcome

Comment: What about `limit 24 offset 24`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT 24, 48` doesn't mean from 24 to 48. it means from 24 to (24+48).
if I say in another way, it starts from 24, get 48 records .

```
LIMIT 24, 24
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

but I recommend you to use `WHERE`

```
SELECT AVG($probe), TIME FROM tbl_sensors
WHERE `TIME` BETWEEN ... AND ...
GROUP BY DATE(TIME), HOUR(TIME)
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 24
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I had missundertood LIMIT, i'll use it rather than BETWEEN as I can just increment a variable by 24 to get the next day's data.